# Android Studio build errors when project is in a subfolder of Github

Tags: android, github, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, atlassian-sourcetree

I created a new project in Android Studio and I put the project folder inside another folder in Github. It's like this `Code/ProjectName`

However I'm having problems when I try to build my project with Gradle, this is the output in the Gradle Console:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ProjectName\Code\ProjectName-Ver-0\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-mdpi\abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ProjectName\Code\ProjectName-Ver-0\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file

Error: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\UserName\Java\AndroidStudioSDK\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe s -i C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ProjectName\Code\ProjectName-Ver-0\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png -o C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ProjectName\Code\ProjectName-Ver-0\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png
Error Code:
    42
Output:
    C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ProjectName\Code\ProjectName-Ver-0\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file

:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\UserName\Java\AndroidStudioSDK\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe s -i C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ProjectName\Code\ProjectName-Ver-0\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png -o C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ProjectName\Code\ProjectName-Ver-0\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png
Error Code:
    42
Output:
    C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ProjectName\Code\ProjectName-Ver-0\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.013 secs
```

Not only that.

I also get an error that says `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'`

I think it has to do with the fact that the project code is inside a sub folder of Github. But I need to have it there.

I created another project to test and I don't get any of this error since is not connected to Github.

**Extra**:
So I confirmed that if I take the project folder out of the Github root folder, the project does not show me these errors when I open it on Android Studio.

If anyone knows why does this happen and there is a way to fix it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have any spaces in the project name?  This can cause problems.

Comment: No spaces at all. If I take out the folder out of the Github root folder and put it anywhere else it works, the project does not have these errors. The problem is when I open the project from the Github root folder. And I wondering why is this happening and how I can fix it.

Comment: Can you post the directory structure of the project?  Android Studio creates a directory for the project and then the app is inside a nested directory (module).  So it seems that the project structure is ok but I'd like to see it.  Also, you seem to be saying you're building from Github, not Android Studio - not sure what that means.

Comment: @AzharBandri, Yes! the problem was the project path was very long and there is a 255 character file path limit in Windows 7. My original project name was also way longer than the one I put in my example. I fixed it by cloning the project in C:\ instead of Documents and also changing the project name to something much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a git repository with the same name of the project
2. clone it to the folder where the Android project lies. ( copy cut paste the project to another folder (CopyFolder) before cloning .

   so, after cloning you will get a folder  with the same project name as before. with no contents there will be only a .git file .  let it be there .
3. copy and paste the contents of your actual Android project in (CopyFolder) to the cloned folder. Make sure you only contents inside the folder is needed not he entire folder.

(if you are using git bash to update git use these commands )

```
git add .
git commit -m " updated "
git push
```

and there you go ... run the project. It wont show any error.